# setup.bash missing after Ubuntu upgrade 12.04 > 13.10

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Last week I updated my Ubuntu to use some new features with regards to my video card and I was already worried when I saw a lot of ros-groovy things passing by during the upgrades.
Now after the upgrades it seems that Ros Groovy has been reinstalled and my setup.bash is missing from /opt/ros/groovy/ where it used to be. (my .bashrc still refers there but gives me file not found)

Now I am trying to reinstall ros-groovy-desktop-full but I am getting impossible dependencies. ros-groovy-rviz is dependent on libogre-dev which is dependent on libboost1.49 but ros-groovy-rviz its other depencies depend on libboost1.53.

$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-groovy-desktop-full : Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.3.1-0quantal-20140127-1116-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.6-s1390816612~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.13-s1390743952~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.34-0quantal-20140127-0905-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Does anyone have any information regarding this so I can continue development for my project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127126/setup.bash-missing-after-ubuntu-upgrade-12.04-%3E-13.10/) by [Gullydwarf](https://answers.ros.org/users/7076/gullydwarf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-07**:
As far as I know groovy isn't even released for 13.10, so the reason that setup.bash is missing is probably that everything is missing and you're just dealing with left-overs. Someone official might confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

groovy (and hydro) is not supported on Saucy. As @dornhege said, anything related to ROS that you're seeing is probably leftover and shouldn't be there at all.

See [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for the target platforms for each release.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0